# Set System to always use Rounded Font?

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI, is there a way to make the rounded version of the system font the default for all styles? I'm using one of the system styles (.body, .title, .headline, etc) for all text in the app.

For example, I can use this on a single Text view

```swift
Text("some text")
    .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded))
```

I'd like to avoid having to update every text view and field in my app like this. Is there some way to tell the environment to use the rounded design by default?

Comment: I referred to @Environment(\.font), but it appeared read-only

Answer (score 8):

Here is how it is possible to set environment font in root view, all subviews will have it by default.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Details")) {
                Text("Link")
            }
            Text("Tap on image to find details")
        }
    }.environment(\.font, Font.system(.body, design: .rounded))
}
```

Comment: This sets a single default font for all text in a view. I'm looking for a way to always use the rounded design, regardless of the style I use. This does not do that.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer. However, `Text`-Views in the navigation bar are not changed to the new font. And the following approach results in an error that the `Text` no longer conforms to the string protocol.
`.navigationBarTitle(Text("Title").environment(\.font, Font.custom(Fonts.plex, size: 28)))`
Any ideas how to get the font changed system wide?

Answer (score 3):

You could create an extension on `Font` that has a function that automatically sets the design to being rounded, while still allowing you to set the `TextStyle`

```
extension Font {
    static func roundedFont(_ style: Font.TextStyle) -> Font {
        Font.system(style, design: .rounded)
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello").font(.roundedFont(.body))
    }
}
```

Comment: I would still have to update every view in the app that uses a text style, so I don't see how this would solve my problem.

Comment: I don't think there is the way to do what you want. I don't think you can override the system font

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 16.1 you can use `.fontDesign(.rounded)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fontdesign(_:)

Answer (score -1):

You could create an extension on `Font` like below

1. Parameter Font `size` & `weight`
2. Parameter Font `TextStyle`

   ```
   extension Font {
      static func roundedFont(WithSize size: CGFloat, AndWeight weight:Weight) -> Font {
          return Font.system(size: size, weight: weight, design: .rounded)
      }

      static func roundedFont(_ style: Font.TextStyle) -> Font {
          return Font.system(style, design: .rounded)
      }
   }
   ```

You can call like:

```
- Text("Hello").font(Font.roundedFont(WithSize: 15.0, AndWeight: .bold))
- Text("Hello").font(Font.roundedFont(.body))
```

Comment: This is not any different than the answer given by @Andrew above and it does not solve OP's main question. You still have to call the extension method everywhere and it does not apply those fonts automatically to entire app which is what the question is.